# How do you get punctuation to work with RTL languages?

Tags: html, css

How do you get periods to appear at the end of the paragraph in RTL languages?

```html
<p dir="rtl" style="float: right;direction: rtl;">   
    .זהו משפט בשפה מימין לשמאל
</p>
```

Here's a screenshot of how it is incorrectly rendered on my hosted site. The red arrow is where the period is located. The green arrow is where it **should** be placed:

[image]

Interestingly enough, when rendered here in the browser, it does work:

.זהו משפט בשפה מימין לשמאל

Comment: What are you seeing and what are you hoping to see? I see no period in your example and it displays exactly as your example shows, if it had a period in the raw html on the right, it would display the period on the left as you expect.

Comment: @ChrisW. I updated the question with a more relevant example

Comment: @larry909 After having played around with it myself, I believe it's normal behavior for the textual encoding, which interprets the period as ltr because it's already in ltr mode when it encounters the period. It doesn't switch to rtl mode until it finds a character that definitely needs rtl. (And, this all happens before the `dir="rtl"` gets to take effect, because the document is considered *textual* before gets interpreted as HTML.) But, how to fix it? IDK.

Comment: @jpaugh yeah, I see, thanks, some good info there.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit

After having played around with it myself, I'm convinced that the issue is happening in the textual encoding, which must be interpreted before the browser gets a chance to apply its own HTML rules.

In other words, since this rtl text is preceded by ltr text (namely the html document itself), the textual decoder is in an ltr context when it reads the period. The period itself will not change the text direction. However, inserting a [right-to-left mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) seems to have no effect.

```html
<p dir="rtl" style="float: right;direction: rtl;">   
    &rlm;.זהו משפט בשפה מימין לשמאל
</p>
```

---

## Figuring things out

Note the difference between your placement of the period, and the placement used in [Mozilla's rtl examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir).

I think the issue happens (partly) because the period itself has no directionality. When you place the period at the left in the source, it gets moved to the beginning of the output, because the period is in an ltr context within the text itself.

In an ltr context (as in your first example), it ends up on the left; in an rtl context (as in your second example), it ends up on the right. When you use a direction of auto, the browser chooses rtl, as you can see below. That shows that the first strongly directional character is the `ל`, not the `.`.

```html
<p dir="ltl">
    .זהו משפט בשפה מימין לשמאל
</p>
<p dir="rtl">
    .זהו משפט בשפה מימין לשמאל
</p>
<br>
<p dir="auto">
    .זהו משפט בשפה מימין לשמאל
</p>
```

When I try editing the text, above, it switches between an rtl and an ltr context depending on whether I'm typing before or after the period. I think the issue has to do with the textual encoding itself. You might need to place an rtl marker before the beginning of the text, or "after" the period.

Interestingly, if you place the period within a larger block of text, it works. Since it's not the left-most character in the source text, it doesn't create an implicit ltr context before the rtl context of the other text.

```html
    <p dir="rtl">
        זהו משפט בשפה מימין לשמאל. לשמאל
    </p>
    <p dir="rtl">
        .זהו משפט בשפה מימין לשמאל 
    </p>
```

See the difference?

Comment: I tried without any direction attributes and in some cases when the paragraph was only on one line the punctuation did display at the end properly.

Comment: I think like you mentioned it has to do with the textual encoding of the file itself.

Comment: @larry909 There might be some Unicode questions on here already. I'm not really an expert, as you must have guessed by now.

Comment: better than me tho :) your answer was enlightening